# How to remove white stain after stove cleaning?

Tags: oven, cleaning

I cleaned the gate of my stove using *easy off* oven cleaner and then had some white stains that cannot be removed:

[image]

How do I remove the stains?

Comment: Have you tried a thin film of oil? Drizzle a small amount of oil on a cloth or piece of kitchen tissue. If that doesn't help, I'd guess that the metal itself is tarnished

Comment: Googling I only find 'Easy **off**' cleaner. A link to the brand would help, so that we can look at its ingredient list.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, it is Easy off cleaner. My apologies.

Comment: Easy-Off's site says it's fine for stainless steel.. How absolutely 100% certain are you that your door handle is actually stainless steel. I've seen heavy cleaners do damage like that on metals containing brass, copper, nickel etc, but never stainless steel. The fact it appears to have damaged the handle but not the door face would reinforce that possibility.

Comment: That looks to me like it's a plastic handle with a metallic plating - and you've started to rub the plating off, exposing the plastic underneath.

Comment: It's been a few months; did you figure out a solution? Is the handle really metal or plastic? Can you come back to comment / self-answer the question? Check [answer] if you have any doubts.